# Rails - Deleted public/index.html - Now browser shows directory structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I recently installed Ruby on Rails on my Windows 7.

```
ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10) [i386-mingw32]
rails --version
Rails 3.2.9
```

I am using apache and have edited my httpd.conf file with the following:

```
Listen 3000
DocumentRoot "C:/Users/username/Documents/GitHub/blog/public"

<Directory "C:/Users/username/Documents/GitHub/blog/public">
    Options Indexes +FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

When I go to localhost:3000 I get the default Welcome aboard You’re riding Ruby on Rails! message.  So I ran the following command:

```
$ rails generate controller home index
```

That created all of the files I would have expected.  I then edited routes.rb to have the following line:

```
root :to => 'home#index'
```

And when I reload the browswer, instead of directing me to the index.html file in my /app/views/home folder it displays a Directory Structure of my /public folder.

Does anyone know what step I may have missed?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you want to remove the `Indexes` or add a `-` like this `-Indexes`
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#options